# Updating a Datagridview (C#)

Tags: c#

I can't seem to find a solution on the internet to my dilemma here.  I have a datagrid that has a preset datasource in the control properties.  So i don't have to code anything for the datagrid view to show my table data.  Now I have a button that adds a new row into my table and it works fine but I can't get my datagridview to update the information.

I tried using resetbindings hoping it would update my datagrid control but it doesn't.
Any tips?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlcom.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO members (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text +"', '"+ textBox2.Text +"')";
        sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        thisConnect.Close();

        //update datagridview?
        this.membersBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);

    }
```

Comment: what type of project is it ? Web / windows ?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out.  I setup a new sqladapter and dataset then set the datagridview datasource and datamember it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Cant u write following two lines:

```
DataSourceID.DataBind();
YourdatagridviewID.DataSource=DataSourceIDhere
```

in place of the line:
`this.membersBindingSource.ResetBindings(false)`;

???